# Chess and mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, game-theory

I have to choose a research-like project to follow the next year. Because I'm a chess enthusiast, I was thinking of trying to tackle an (open) problem related to chess, and relevant to mathematics.

Can you suggest some material on the "mathematical side of chess" and related problems?

Comment: One thing that has puzzled me for quite some time: Given two **perfect** players $A$ and $B$, where $A$ has only a king, a knight and a bishop left, and $B$ has only a king left - can $A$ beat $B$? (although I suppose it's not sufficient for a research project).

Comment: @barakmanos: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop_and_knight_checkmate), with a couple of exceptions.

Comment: @DanielR: What I meant is - If $B$ is perfect, will he/she be able to avoid being check-mated (even if $A$ is also perfect)?

Comment: @barakmanos No, it takes at most $35$ moves to force a mate against a perfect opponent, unless the position is such that the weaker side can force a stalemate or capture a piece. All according to the link I posted above.

Comment: @DanielR: Got it, thanks :)

Comment: the bishop+knight thing is always a win if Black cannot capture a piee on the first move.

Comment: Not quite correct : The sole king can in very rare cases win a piece in the next move without immediately capturing one. Curiousity fact : A 2600+ player could not win such an endgame in a tournament game (not blitz or rapid) , the win is not easy. Also , the longest checkmate sequence is $33$ , not $35$.

Comment: In the position N7/8/8/3k4/8/8/1K6/B7 b - - 0 1 , black needs even two moves to attack the knight and still with black to move , it is a draw.

Answer (score 3):

The [Knights tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_tour) is a  famous chess/math problem.

Answer (score 2):

Start [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/chess.html).

Comment: This answer was flagged as low quality. As link only answers are often undesirable, I marked the flag as helpful. That was converted to a downvote, which mechanism had somehow escaped my attention until now. I think Noam Elkies' page is one of the best sources (IIRC at least at one point he was working on a book about math problems in chess), so that was not my intention. Compensating with an upvote. Sorry about the mixed signals to all.

Answer (score 2):

I studied rook polynomials.  This problem asks how many rooks can be placed on a board in non-taking positions and has applications in scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a chess engine that plays only moderately well, is a considerable programming challenge. Imo, very few people have the discipline, ability and patience to actually organize and execute something like that from scratch, programming-wise.

There are some open sources which you can see and read, like that of GNU chess, Borland's Turbo chess and several others which have ended up public, yet it still is fairly difficult to even manage to improve some already existing engine.

I'd gladly consider it a fairly hot subject for a Ph.D. thesis.

Comment: How much elo is only moderately well? Also, you agree that is even harder to create engine that plays better than a engine that plays worst? Lasy question to understand your post.

Comment: Moderately well is in the range 1000-1600. Yes, I agree to your second question. The hard part with a chess engine is fine tune it to play in the 1900-2700 range.

Comment: Yes, I think we agree. I was asking you this: In my view (I haven't programmed chess engines ever, but I imagine works like this) If the elo of the engine is higher, it's harder to program. Someone could have a thepry that for some reason is hard to do "dumb" engines. However, seems to me you can just make it play some times the 5th best move, or the 10th best move (there are about 35 moves per position available, and those moves after 10 are rather bad)  with random chance, and play good moves with some probability, so that you can make as low elo as you want..

Answer (score 0):

The following link in chess.stackexchange https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27259/has-anyone-attempted-to-characterize-chess-mathematically is a quick sketch I made of some math areas for chess. Something might catch your interest - please ask me if you want to know more.

In the most recent issue of the Spanish magazine Problemas, there’s an article (in English) attempting to resuscitate the genre of mathematical chess problems for the prestigious FIDE Album. Perhaps a bit dry, it has been well-received by the chess problem community. See issue 40 at the bottom of http://sepa64.blogspot.com/p/revista-problemas-nueva-epoca.html?m=1.

Chess is really so plastic a form, that it’s perhaps best to ask what kind of mathematics interests you, and I can maybe give more focused examples of what folk have been doing in this space.